# What is this structure called? Simply SoA?

Tags: c, simd

I've seen common comparisons made between the AoS (Array of Structures):

```
struct xyz
{
    ALIGNED float x, y, z, ignored;
};
ALIGNED struct xyz AoS[n];
```

And the SoA (Structure of Arrays):

```
struct SoA
{
    ALIGNED_AND_PADDED float x[n];
    ALIGNED_AND_PADDED float y[n];
    ALIGNED_AND_PADDED float z[n];
};
```

So what would this kind of data representation be called?

```
struct xyz4
{
    ALIGNED float x[4];
    ALIGNED float y[4];
    ALIGNED float z[4];
};
ALIGNED struct xyz4[n/4] ???;
```

A "cache-efficient SoA"? An AoSoA? An SoAoS? A "PITA to code"? It seems like the most efficient solution generally speaking, providing SoA-type SIMD with a lot of cache hits.

Comment: I think that the increased cache efficiency will be offset by the indexing math, e.g. `float x = xyz4[index/4].x[index%4]`.

Comment: Often I'm used to cases where the bulk processing needs to be done sequentially (over a given range per thread), so I think one could avoid making that computation per entry. It seems quite efficient in theory anyway, but I've always found it too much of a pain to code and really test out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That data structure has multiple names such as a Hybrid Structure of Arrays (see [Extending a C-like Language for Portable SIMD Programming](http://www.cdl.uni-saarland.de/papers/leissa_vecimp_tr.pdf)) or an array of struct of arrays (AoSoA).

AoS is not suitable for SIMD. SoA is an improvement but in some cases is still not sufficient. The solution is a Hybrid Structure of Arrays. It may be a PITA as you say but that's what you have to use sometimes if you want the highest efficient from SIMD (unless gather and scatter instructions become efficient).

Comment: Perfect -- I like this name very much. I have often been using the AoS just simply because I tried the alternate SoA but then started getting negligible improvements (I suspected due to cache misses). So I was tempted to try this hybrid structure out. One of my challenges has always been to just try to make that more practical to code with, especially since I'm working with data structures that are meant to be accessed from a public interface, and are not merely implementation details of a high-level algorithm.