# Does packed data type in SSE2 imply alignment?

Tags: assembly, sse, memory-alignment, sse2

I'm writing some code that should utilize some type of vectorized instructions in order to compare two arrays consisting of 64-bit integers. I'm thinking of utilizing the SSE2 variant for [`cmpeq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpeqb:pcmpeqw:pcmpeqd). The term I am getting stuck on is the term 'packed'.

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473189/what-is-a-packed-structure-in-c), I get the sense that packed simply means that there is no space between variables. This makes sense for me. However, reading [assembly code for `memcmp`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/memcmp.S#l162), they talk about alignment (note that the function compares bytes, and not 64-bit integers).

So, if I would like to compare the register `xmm0` to something in the memory, does the memory address have to be 128-bit aligned, or is it okay for it to be only 64-bit aligned?

Comment: It needs to be 128 bit aligned. _"Non-EVEX-encoded instruction, see Exceptions Type 4."_  and _"Table 2-21. Type 4 Class Exception Conditions: Memory operand is not 16-byte aligned."_

Comment: You can avoid the alignment requirement by using an unaligned load, the linked code tries to avoid them and that has some benefits but it's not as if you *have* to avoid them.

Comment: What do you mean by unaligned load, @harold?

Comment: `movdqu` for example, has no alignment requirement.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't connect load with move. Thanks.

Comment: @Jester There should be no alignment requirement for AVX/AVX2 either.

Comment: I  know, but the question is titled and tagged SSE2.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate [Alignment and SSE strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38443452) - although the behaviour in that question is explained by the difference between movdqa and movdqu, which my answer explains.